# C - printf doesn't display full string

Tags: c, string, pointers, printf

I'm trying to concatenate two strings, separated by a space, by using pointers instead of strcat. I've gotten the concatenation to work but when I try to print the concatenated string it just prints the first string.

CODE:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    char string1[10];
    char string2[10];
    char fullString[21];

    char *string1Ptr = string1;
    char *string2Ptr = string2;
    char *fullStringPtr = fullString;

    printf("Enter first string: ");
    scanf_s("%s", &string1, 10);
    fflush(stdin);

    printf("Enter second string: ");
    scanf_s("%s", &string2, 10);
    fflush(stdin);

    for (int i = 0; i < 21; ++i){
        if (i < 10){
            fullStringPtr[i] = string1Ptr[i];
        }
        else if (i == 10){
            fullStringPtr[i] = ' ';
        }
        else if (i > 10){
            fullStringPtr[i] = string2Ptr[i - 11];
        }
    }

    printf("%s\n", fullString);
    //printf("%c", fullString[11]);

    getchar();
    return (0);
}
```

If I enter Hello as the first string and World as the second, the printout just reads "Hello." However, if I try to print the character in a specific position in the second string, e.g. fullString[11], I get the character that should be in that position, in this case W.

The second string is obviously there, printf just doesn't print it. Is there something about printf that I'm missing?

Comment: `fullString` is stored as `"Hello\0\0\0\0\0 World\0\0\0\0\0\0"`, but since C strings are null-terminated, `printf` stops at the first `\0`

Comment: So... in your loop check for \0 and replace with a space, while processing the first string.

Comment: @EricJ. that woulnd't work, because that way uninitialized values could be copied, causing undefined behavior.

Comment: Oh right... so @frxstrem's statement is also not necessarily correct as values after the first \0 in the first string are undefined.  So I guess set to space things copied from the first string at and beyond the first \0, no matter what the source byte is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In c strings are defined as a sequence of bytes with a terminating `'\0'` byte, so `"A\0"` would represent the string `A` and `"A\0ABCDEF"` would also represent the string `"A"`, `scanf` appends this `'\0'` special value that delimits the string to the array, so copying each character you also copy this byte.

Not only that, if you input for example `ABC` at the first `scanf`, then the contents of the array would be

```
[A|B|C|\0|?|?|?|?|?|?]
 0 1 2  3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

where `?` means `UNINITIALIZED` they are random garbage values from the previous contents of the memory at those spots, so trying to read those values is undefined behavior.

You are copying the `'\0'` from the first string into the middle of the resulting string, i suggest 2 loops

```
int j = 0;

for (i = 0 ; string1Ptr[i] != '\0' ; ++i)
    fullStringPtr[j++] = string1Ptr[i];

fullStringPtr[j++] = ' ';

for (i = 0 ; string2Ptr[i] != '\0' ; ++i)
    fullStringPtr[j++] = string2Ptr[i];
fullStringPtr[j++] = '\0';
```

`printf` prints each character encounterd before a `'\0'` is found, and since you copied that value from the first string into the second, it should be printing the first string only, the characters after the `'\0'` are omited.

Or simply use `strcat` if you can include the `string.h` header

```
fullStringPtr[0] = '\0';

strcat(fullStringPtr, string1Ptr);
strcat(fullStringPtr, " ");
strcat(fullStringPtr, string2Ptr);
```

Comment: Ah, I was actually going to get rid of the uninitialized positions, but I wanted to make sure the strings were copied over correctly first, then I ran into to this. It never occurred to me that that was what was causing the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

When you copy from `firstString` and `secondString`, `fullString` is stored as `"Hello\0\0\0\0\0 World\0\0\0\0\0\0"`, but since C strings are null-terminated, `printf` stops printing the string at the first `\0` it finds.

Others have posted other solutions to this, but I would like to add that the simplest is probably by using [`strcpy`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy) and [`strcat`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcat):

```
strcpy(fullStringPtr, string1Ptr); // copy to fullString
strcat(fullStringPtr, " ");        // add to end of fullString
strcat(fullStringPtr, string2Ptr); // add to end of fullString

printf("%s\n", fullString); // works as expected
```

Comment: Normally I would use strcpy and strcat but I wanted to practice using pointers.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the string concatenation code.

You happen to have some `'\0'`s embedded in the `fullString` destination buffer, and since C strings are `'\0'`-terminated, `printf()` stops printing when it finds the first `'\0'` in the destination buffer.

To fix that, you can change the string concatenation code, like this:

1. copy characters from first string into destination buffer (update string pointers accordingly)
2. write a space  in the destination buffer (and update dest string pointer accordingly)
3. copy characters from the second string into the destination buffer (updating string pointers accordingly)

This can be written in C code like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char string1[10];
    char string2[10];
    char fullString[21];

    char *string1Ptr = string1;
    char *string2Ptr = string2;
    char *fullStringPtr = fullString;

    printf("Enter first string: ");
    scanf_s("%s", string1, 10);
    fflush(stdin);

    printf("Enter second string: ");
    scanf_s("%s", string2, 10);
    fflush(stdin);

    /* Reality-check: print read strings */
    printf("First string:  %s\n", string1);
    printf("Second string: %s\n", string2);

    /* Copy string1 to dest buffer */
    while (*string1Ptr != '\0')
    {
        *fullStringPtr = *string1Ptr;
        ++fullStringPtr;
        ++string1Ptr;
    }

    /* Add space */
    *fullStringPtr = ' ';
    ++fullStringPtr;

    /* Concat string2 to dest buffer */
    while (*string2Ptr != '\0')
    {
        *fullStringPtr = *string2Ptr;
        ++fullStringPtr;
        ++string2Ptr;
    }

    /* Terminate full string */
    *fullStringPtr = '\0';

    /* Print result */
    printf("%s\n", fullString);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> ```
> Enter first string: Hello
> Enter second string: World
> First string:  Hello
> Second string: World
> Hello World
> ```

---

**NOTE**

Unless you wrote this code as a learning experience to understand pointers, etc. consider using built-in string copy and concatenation functions like `strcpy()`/`strcat()`, or better their safer versions like `strcpy_s()` and `strcat_s()`.